# what is the difference between Sleep mode and Deep sleep mode?

Tags: android

I would like to know what is the difference between Sleep mode and Deep sleep mode in android phone and what will be the impact of when phone goes to sleep mode and deep sleep mode.

Please provide me the answer in details.

regards,
Piks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deep sleep mode doesn't have anything to do with hibernate and boot time, as somebody wrote in deleted answer.

You should not avoid the phone sleep, this will drain your battery very fast. To receive messages from server, you should use <s>[C2DM]</s> [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) which has the same basic characteristics as old fashion [deprecated C2DM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html).

More info about the android sleep here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: there is still no accepted answer so I suppose somebody deleted the one you were refering too..

Comment: "As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](http://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) to learn more." - [https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm)

Answer (score 3):

You can use WAKE_LOCK to prevent device going to deep sleep. But you must take into account battery drain. More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Answer (score 2):

Deep sleep: turns your phone CPU *central processing unit ie brain* to the lowest clock cycle speed. On mine it is 200mhz, where max is 1600mhz.

it also disables some sensors it figures you might not be using, such as *dependin on phone* camera, gyro, etc. some of it gets shut off to save power.

When you wake up your phone *depending on governer*, it rams cpu clock cycle up to 500mhz, or 800mhz, or 1600mhz, and re activates the sensors, sending power back to the camera, cyro, magnet, etc that your phone may have *proxi sensor*

This is more or less what deep sleep really IS. program, to save power, by disableing unused sensors, and clocking cpu way down to minimum.

Credits: vrigil kellogg http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-s-iii/247066-what-deep-sleep.html post#14