# notification localization for data-only firebase push

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, localization, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have overrided `public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` in `FirebaseMessagingService`.

Then i send data-only push.

When screen of device is on `onMessageReceived` is called successfully. Some little time after device locking (screen is off) `onMessageReceived` is called successfully too (for another sended push of course).

But if device is in **deep sleep** mode then `onMessageReceived` is not called until i press lock/power button.

Are there any idea, how to popup notification in deep sleep as soon as push sended?

PS: if i use notification-payload in firebase push - i can't localize it in android app (if you have any idea about it - it's superb too).

Comment: My problem is  that _onMessageReceived is not called_ for _data-only push_ in _deep sleep_. "If your payload contains only a data key, your app will handle all push messages itself. E.g. they are all delivered to your onMessageReceived handler." - is not solution to popup notification as soon as push sended.

Comment: What is deep sleep?

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119034/what-is-the-difference-between-sleep-mode-and-deep-sleep-mode). I my case - about 5minutes after screen-off (device locking).

Comment: What device are you using? Have you tried this on another device or emulator?

Comment: I have tried on 3 real devices (including Nexus 7) with 4.2, 5.1 android. If push occurs in ~5 minutes interval after device locking - it's ok, but if later (for example ~10 min) push notification is lagged for minutes or received immediately after manual unlocking only.

Comment: Resolved with delay_while_idle=0 on server